# Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to get info from DB and when I do, I'm getting this error:

> > An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
> >
> > > Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double GetBalance(Int32, Double, Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The code is this:

```
public Model GetData(int saleId)
{
        using (var context = new ABCD())
        {
            var data = context.MY_TABLE
                .Where(w => w.ID == saleId)
                .Select(s => new Model
                {
                    ClinicId = s.CLINIC_ID,
                    PatientId = s.PATIENT_ID,
                    Date = s.DOS,
                    ProductBalance = GetBalance(s.ID, (double)s.TOTAL_PRICE, (double)s.TAX_PERCENTAGE),
                })
                .First();

            return data;
        }
}
```

The 'GetBalance()' function is used in more other parts in my code, but I'm not having problems with it. This is the function:

```
public double GetBalance(int saleId, double TotalCharge, double TaxPercent) {
        var ChargeWithTax = Math.Round((TotalCharge + ((TaxPercent / 100) * TotalCharge)), 2);
        var PaymentWriteOff = Math.Round(GetPayments(saleId) + GetTotalWriteOff(saleId), 2);
        return Math.Floor((ChargeWithTax - PaymentWriteOff) * 100) / 100;
    }
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Missing `using` possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provider doesn't recognize your local method `GetBalance` and can't translate it into raw SQL.

You can get a normal database object, and create the local object using local methods locally:

```
var s = context.MY_TABLE.First(w => w.ID == saleId);

var data = new Model()
{
    ClinicId = s.CLINIC_ID,
    PatientId = s.PATIENT_ID,
    Date = s.DOS,
    ProductBalance = GetBalance(s.ID, (double)s.TOTAL_PRICE, (double)s.TAX_PERCENTAGE)
};

return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a very bad practice of calling a method within IQueryable in LINQ.

Your are tried to call the Method `GetBalance()`. We can't do that.

For more detailed explanation read http://www.increvcorp.com/usage-of-asenumerable-and-asqueryable-in-linq/